# Remove duplicate trees from an array of root nodes using a recursive __hash__() function in python

Tags: python, hash

I am attempting to remove duplicates trees from an array of root nodes. I am trying this by creating a custom **hash**() function and putting the variety of root nodes into a set to remove duplicates. Below is my faulty implementation.

```
class Node: 
def __init__(self, entity, size, delay, left_child, right_child, padding): 
    # self.key = key 
    self.entity = entity
    self.size = size
    self.delay = delay
    self.left_child = left_child
    self.right_child = right_child
    self.padding = padding


def __hash__(self):
    if self is None:
        return hash(None)

    return hash(('delay', self.delay, 'size', self.size, 'entity', self.entity, 'padding', self.padding,  
    'left_child', hash(self.left_child),
    'right_child', hash(self.right_child)))
```

Upon running the following code, I am given an array of length three instead of an expected array length of two because there are only two unique roots in the set as node2 has the same values as node1.

```
node0 = Node(1, 1, 1, None, None, None)
node1 = Node(1, 2, 3, node0, node0, None)
node2 = Node(1, 2, 3, node0, node0, None)
remove_duplicate_test = list(set([node0, node0, node1, node1, node2, node2]))
```

Quite unexpectedly, the following code does return the expected array of length two. I assumed that it would return the same output as the above code snippet as it is essentially the same code, but alas.

```
node0 = Node(1, 1, 1, None, None, None)
node1 = Node(1, 2, 3, node0, node0, None)
node2 = node1
remove_duplicate_test = list(set([node0, node0, node1, node1, node2, node2]))
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

previous **eq**() function that has errors

```
def __eq__(self, other):
        if self is None and other is None:
            return True
    
        # 2. Both non-empty -> Compare them
        if self is not None and other is not None:
            return ((self.delay == other.delay and 
                    self.size == other.size and 
                    self.entity == other.entity and 
                    self.padding == other.padding) and 
                    __eq__(self.left_child, other.left_child) and
                    __eq__(self.right_child, other.right_child))
        
        # 3. one empty, one not -- false
        return False
```

Comment: Defining `__hash__()` without `__eq__()` is not very useful.  Without an explicit definition of equality, sets only consider multiple references to the same object to be equal.

Answer (score 1):

The "duplicate" nodes in the set will only be removed if the nodes compare as equal, which they won't unless you define your own `__eq__` method.  The rule is that if two instances of an object compare as equal, then they *must* have the same hash value.  However, it is possible for two objects that have the same hash value not to compare as equal.  You can fix that by defining your own `__eq__` method.

Try adding the following method to your class:

```
def __eq__(self, node2):
    return self.entity      == node2.entity and \
           self.size        == node2.size and \
           self.delay       == node2.delay and \
           self.left_child  == node2.left_child and \
           self.right_child == node2.right_child and \
           self.padding     == node2.padding
```

This will make two nodes with the same fields compare as equal.  Together with your `__hash__` method, this should result in duplicate (equivalent) nodes in a set being removed.

Note:  You should really make the class immutable if you're defining `__hash__` like this.  Otherwise, if you change one of the attribute values of an instance that's in a `set` or `dict`, it will be stored with the wrong hash value.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added my previous __eq__() fuction in my post. This one does not work as  the recursive calls to __eq__() redline saying __eq__() is not defined.

Comment: @Joe You need to restart Python so that *all* of your node instances use the new class.  Then it will work recursively.

Comment: Also note that you should really make the class immutable if you want to hash based on the attribute values of a class instance.

Comment: Also note that using the hash value an equality test does *not* work.  All it tells you is that two instances *may* have the same attribute values.  But they may not.  They only way to know for certain is to compare the attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

Using set find node2 as a duplicate of node1 because they are different variables.  If you use your hash function as the unique items, though, that should work because the hash of node1 should be the same as the hash of node2.  Then you need to figure out how to line up the hash with the nodes.  You could do that with iteration rather than list comprehension:

```
node_set = set()
node_hash_set = set()
for node in [node0, node1, node2]:
    hash_of_node = hash(node) 
    if hash_of_node not in node_hash_set:
        node_hash_set.add(hash_of_node)
        node_set.add(node)
```

Comment: Excellent, please vote for / accept my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work.  It will occasionally incorrectly remove different nodes that *happen* to have the same hash, even if some of their fields are different.  It is absolutely the wrong way to try to "solve" this problem. See my answer for the correct way to fix this (OP seemingly didn't use the new class so thought it didn't work, but it does).